# Defining own pad in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am using a simple convolutional network, however, I need to use very specific paddings: I want to copy the nearest pixel value, something like this:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

to

```
1  1  2  3  3
1  1  2  3  3
4  4  5  6  6
7  7  8  9  9
7  7  8  9  9
```

While I have no problem calculating the pad itself, I cannot use it in convolution. Is there a way to put these values into a tensorflow pad? Or I can modify the image, so it will contain the pad, but how can I set the convolution to handle the first and last rows and columns as padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simnply call `tf.pad` with symmetric mode before your call to `conv2d`, while specifying that the convolution should use the `VALID` padding mode:

```
>>> a = tf.reshape(tf.range(9),(3,3))
>>> a
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.]], dtype=float32)>
>>> padded_a = tf.pad(a,[[1,1],[1,1]],"SYMMETRIC")
>>> padded_a
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 1., 2., 2.],
       [0., 0., 1., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 4., 5., 5.],
       [6., 6., 7., 8., 8.],
       [6., 6., 7., 8., 8.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Now, if we create a simple 3x3 filter made of 1, we should have as result of the convolution the sum of the neighbouring elements (pad included), with the same shape as our original input:

```
>>> filters = tf.ones((3,3,1,1))
>>> conv_result = tf.nn.conv2d(padded_a[tf.newaxis,:,:,tf.newaxis], filters, padding="VALID", strides=1)
>>> tf.squeeze(conv_result) # just removing the batch and channel dimensions
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[12., 18., 24.],
       [30., 36., 42.],
       [48., 54., 60.]], dtype=float32)>
```